# Big O notation (Complexity)

Tags: java, big-o, complexity-theory

What is the Big O of this loop?
-> i understand that the loop itself is going to execute n times. But the task inside of the loop also executes n times right? So would that make this a O(n^2) or do i not combine them and its a simple O(n)? I personally think it is just O(n) because that is how many times the loop is executing but i would just like some clarification as to why or why not it would be? Any explanations would be helpful as i prepare for my midterm.

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length;i++){
        a[i] = b[i]
    }
```

Comment: The task inside the loop executes n times in total because the loop executes n. So therefore O(n). You could have 5000 lines of code inside the for loop and it would still be O(n) if none of the lines involved a loop.

Comment: I think you're confusing yourself with terminology.  "The loop executes _n_ times" really means "The statement inside the loop executes _n_ times", in this case.  So you shouldn't try to "combine" the two by multiplying them, since they're just different ways of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how many times the code inside the loop executes. Each `a[i] = b[i]` happens `a.length` times, which we will call `n`. So this is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

The loop executes n times and the statement inside n times

But n+n+n = 3n (roughly)  = k*n where k is constant steps which is still O(n)

Answer (score 0):

This loop is `O(n)` where `n` is the length of the array.

The operation you perform inside the loop is `O(1)`, but is repeated `n` times due to your loop, making it `O(1*n) = O(n)` in total.

The following code for instance would be `O(n^2)`

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    a[i][j] = i+j;
  }
}
```

Again we analyse from inside to outside. The inner statement is `O(1)`, but this is executed `n` times by the j-for loop. This result in `O(n)` for the inner (j) for-loop. Next we run this for-loop `n`times making it `O(n*n) = O(n^2)` for the full program.

Does that help to answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

> So would that make this a O(n^2) or do i not combine them and its a
>   simple O(n)?

As long as the code inside the loop executes in constant time (thus no other loops or recursive function calls), you can ignore it. Regardless of what you are doing in the loop, it is O(n).

Comment: Unless the loop would contain *another* loop (or a statement that has itself a complexity other than O(1)). Taking your statement literally creates a contradiction, because a call to a method *containing* the loop would be considered O(1) xD

Answer (score 0):

A good way to view Big-O notation is that it refers to how an algorithm *scales*.

For every element input into the algorithm, how many computationally-meaningful steps must be taken to produce the required output. In this example, your "computationally-meaningful step" is assigning the value of b[i] to a[i]. Obviously, this happens as many times as there are elements in the array. Or to abstract it: it happens *exactly as many times as there are input elements*. Now you can see why it is an O(n) algorithm.

A small modification that would make it O(n^2) would be making a double-nested loop, where for every input element, it must add together the entire array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length;i++){
        for(int k = 0; k < b.length; k++) {
             a[i] += b[k]
        }
}
```

Now you can see that for every input element, we are performing more than one operation (m operations, where m is the size of the b-array.)

As a final note on Big-O notation, there are a variety of these notations (including theta, etc.). Big-O reports the *maximum* scaling for a given algorithm. Meaning that, technically speaking, you could describe your algorithm as O(n^50) and be correct - it's just not an answer your teacher is likely to enjoy. You want to get as close as possible to the scaling.